# Creating thread using Runnable object

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

I am trying to create a thread from an object of a class implementing Runnable from java.lang.Runnable
but its not working.

```
piyush@piyush-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop/java_prog$ javac Runnable.java
Runnable.java:27: error: no suitable constructor found for Thread(counter,String)
    Thread td=new Thread(obj,"bac");
              ^
constructor Thread.Thread(Runnable,AccessControlContext) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; counter cannot be converted to Runnable)
constructor Thread.Thread(ThreadGroup,Runnable) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; counter cannot be converted to ThreadGroup)
constructor Thread.Thread(ThreadGroup,String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; counter cannot be converted to ThreadGroup)
constructor Thread.Thread(Runnable,String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; counter cannot be converted to Runnable)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with - Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

this is the error.
  the code is as follows.........

```
import java.io.*;
interface Runnable{
public void run(); 
}
class counter implements Runnable {
Thread t=Thread.currentThread();
private int x;
public counter(){x=0;}
public int getval(){return x;}
public void run()
{
    try{
    while(x<5){
        System.out.println(t.getName()+ ":" + (x++));
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    System.out.println("Exit from thread:"+t);}
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException");
    }
} 
}
class client {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    counter obj=new counter();
    Thread td=new Thread(obj,"bac");
    td.start();
    int val;
    try{
    do{
        val=obj.getval();
        System.out.println(td.getName()+ ":" + val);
        val=6;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }while(val<5);
  }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException 2");
    }
    System.out.println("Exit from thread:"+td.getName());
    }
}
```

Do i have to create any thread constructor.?
or i m am to access the Runnable class from java.lang library??
what's the issue here??

Comment: First: there is already an existing pre-defined interface Runnable. Don't overwrite predefined names. Then. You have trouble with super basic stuff... You better step back and work on simpler examples before even thinking about threads. Sorry, but your code is a whole mess of mistakes.

Comment: okay.  i will improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to create any thread constructor.? or I am to access the
>   Runnable class from java.lang library?? What's the issue here??

You have to create the `Thread` object by calling `java.lang.Thread` constructor and by providing the object of `java.lang.Runnable` type.
I suggest you have a look at the **`Thread` class constuctors** [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) so that you can spot the issues with your code.

There are other flavors (overloaded) of the constructors in `java.lang.Thread` API which can be used to create `Thread` object, but to begin with, you can focus on `Thread(Runnable target, String name)` for now and understand it (that's what you have tried to use in your code).

The issue with your code is that **you are trying to create your own `Runnable` type object and then passing it to the constructor of the `java.lang.Thread`**, because of which you are facing the `Thread.Thread(Runnable,AccessControlContext)` is not applicable error.

In order to fix the issues, just simply remove your `Runnable` interface definition and use the one JDK i.e., `java.lang.Runnable`. In other words, `java.lang.Thread` class contains the constructor for `java.lang.Runnable` interface and that `Thread` class does't accept your `Runnable` object.

Also, as a side note, remember that you need to follow the java naming conventions i.e., class names should be capitalized (like `class Counter` not `class counter`).

Comment: thanx. @javaguy. i used java.lang.Runnable and it worked.

Comment: i undershoot what mistake i was doing... i apprecite your efforts. thanku .

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
class counter implements Runnable 
{
    private int x;
    public counter(){x=0;}
    public int getval(){return x;}
    public void run()
   {
       try{
       while(x<5){
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ":" + (x++));
          Thread.sleep(250);
                 }
       System.out.println("Exit from thread:"+Thread.currentThread());}
       catch(InterruptedException e){
       System.out.println("InterruptedException");
          }
   } 
}

public class client {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        counter obj=new counter();
        Thread td=new Thread(obj,"bac");
        td.start();
        int val;
        try{
           do{
             val=obj.getval();
             System.out.println(td.getName()+ ":=" + val);
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             }while(val<5);
           }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
         {
               System.out.println("InterruptedException 2");
         }                                  
    System.out.println("Exit from thread:"+td.getName());
    }
}
```